# Sendgrid not updating Dynamic templates

Tags: sendgrid

> Send grid is not letting me update old dynamic template and also if i
> create new Dynamic template, i am still facing this error

This is the error i am facing:
**Your dynamic template version could not be updated.**

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your SendGrid account and it would be best to raise a ticket with [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us).

Comment: I was using CORS extension in chrome. So i turned off and its worked  for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you open up the console in Developer Tools (F12 if you're using Google Chrome), try to see if it's a 401 Unauthorized error code. If this is the case, it just means that you need to reauthorize by logging in again.

To do this without losing the work on your template, just open a new tab in the same window, login again, and go back to the tab with your template id. If you click save, it should now allow you to save.